# how to remove trailing \n inside awk in linux

Tags: linux, awk, ksh

I have an input file like this:

```
Apr 24 2014;
is;
a;
sample;
;
Jun 24 2014 123;
may 25 2014;
is;
b;
sample;
;
Dec 21 2014 987
```

... and I want output like this:

```
Apr 24 2014;is;a;sample;;Jun 24 2014 123
may 25 2014;is;b;sample;;Dec 21 2014 987
```

(I'm using ksh)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a data file containing following content:

```
$ cat file
Apr 24 2014;
is;
a;
sample;
;
Jun 24 2014 123
may 25 2014;
is;
b;
sample;
;
Dec 21 2014 987
```

You can do:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%6?"":RS)}1' file
```

```
Apr 24 2014;is;a;sample;;Jun 24 2014 123
may 25 2014;is;b;sample;;Dec 21 2014 987
```

We set the Output Field Separator to print a new line (default value of `RS`) after every 6th record.

You can redirect the output to another file by saying

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%6?"":RS)}1' file > newfile
```

or do the following to make changes to current file

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%6?"":RS)}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: You should always test positives whenever possible as the resulting code is clearer than testing negatives and removes any possibility of introducing double negatives, so I'd use `ORS=NR%6?"":RS` instead of `ORS=!(NR%6)?RS:""`. I'd also parenthesize the ternary expression for portability: ORS=(NR%6?"":RS)`. +1 though.

Comment: @EdMorton Great feedback as always. Updated the solution to incorporate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Although the title suggests a strict awk solution, there is also  a ksh tag and since it appears to be the only thing the program should do, perhaps this would do too:

```
paste -d'\0' - - - - - - < file
```

Just like with the `awk` version, there is still a trailing semicolon in the first line, that is not present in the output sample. I do not know if that would be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'undef $a if($.%7==0);
           $a.=$_;
           if($.%6==0 ||(eof))
           {$a=~s/\;$//;print $a};' Your_file
```

Tested [here](http://ideone.com/jmaWjV)